# Trouble on initializing a struct with the constructor initialization list

Tags: c++, data-structures, compiler-errors, initialization, arduino

I am programming [Arduino](http://arduino.cc/) and I have trouble when using the following code

```
struct myStruct {
  char variable1[10];
  char variable2[10];
  char variable3[10];

  // Constructor
  myStruct() : variable1({'\0'}), variable2({'\0'}), variable3({'\0'}) {}
};
```

since I get the following error:

```
expected primary-expression before '{' token
```

What is the problem? How can I solve it?

*Note*: The `\0` is used for handling null terminated strings.

---

*BTW*: Why the following code works and the above does not?

```
struct myStruct {
  char variable1[10];
  char variable2[10];
  char variable3[10];
} variable = {{'\0'}, {'\0'}, {'\0'}};;
```

Comment: could you use string?

Comment: @billz - No, I can't.

Comment: do you want to set the char array all zero or to an empty string only ?

Comment: @Mario - I updated the question. However, there are other members that I didn't report in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove parens. Use braces only.

That is, instead of

```
variable1({'\0'})
```

write this,

```
variable1{'\0'}   //removed parens!
```

If you follow that, your code would look like this:

```
myStruct() : variable1{'\0'}, variable2{'\0'}, variable3{'\0'} {}
```

Any compiler that supports C++11 should be able to compile it.

---

In C++03, write this:

```
myStruct() : variable1(), variable2(), variable3() {}
```

That should work for this particular case. That is all you have : value-initialization. C++03 doesn't give you much freedom.

Comment: @Backo: In that case, you cannot initialize your array like that.

Comment: So, how could I make? Thanks anyway.

Comment: The `\0` is used for handling null terminated strings. Your code will work the same?

Comment: If I would like to make it explicit (that is, I would like to state the `\0` in my code) how can I make?

Comment: @Backo: In C++03, you cannot do that in the initialization. Sorry. :(

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you just want to initialise the member variables to empty (C-style) strings, change:

```
  // Constructor
  myStruct() : variable1({'\0'}), variable2({'\0'}), variable3({'\0'}) {}
```

to:

```
  // Constructor
  myStruct() : variable1(""), variable2(""), variable3("") {}
```

#### Edit

Apparently some versions of gcc complain about this usage (see comments below) - this appears to be due to a [bug in gcc](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=43453).

Comment: The `\0` is used for handling null terminated strings. Your code will work the same?

Comment: Yes, `""` is equivalent to `{ '\0' }`, i.e. it sets the first byte to 0.

Comment: @PaulR: Did you try that? I get "error: incompatible types in assignment of ‘const char [1]’ to ‘char [10]’"

Comment: If I would like to make it explicit (that is, I would like to state the `\0`) how can I make?

Comment: @Mike: yes, I checked it with g++ -Wall - what compiler are you using ?

Comment: Different version here (Apple gcc based on LLVM/clang), but I also tried it with `g++ -Wall -std=c++98  ..` just to make sure I wasn't using a recent language feature.

Comment: The code is valid. Seems to be a [bug in gcc](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=43453) for a while.

Comment: @JesseGood: thanks for identifying the gcc bug - I'm always loathe to blame the compiler but it looks like it's called for in this case.

Comment: @Nawaz: Are you sure? The bug report quotes: `The form of initialization (using parentheses or =) is generally insignificant, but does matter when the initializer or the entity being initialized has a class type;`, which AFAIK was the same in C++03.

Answer (score 0):

In C++11, your code should work, although it has rather more brackets than strictly necessary.

In any C++, you could specify value-initialisation to zero-initialise the arrays:

```
myStruct() : variable1(), variable2(), variable3() {}
```

If you're being ultra-paranoid, and don't trust `'\0'` to be equivalent to zero, then you'd have to write to the arrays in the constructor body.

> Why the following code works and the above does not?

Because it's always been possible to aggregate-initialise variables in a declaration. It's only since 2011 that it's been possible to do that in a member initialiser.